# Find the Last Index of a Non-Zero Digit using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, node.js

How can you find the last occurrence of a non-zero digit in a number/string in Javascript? With that, we will be able to split a zero-padded number into the actual number and its zero padding. Any JS/Node library can be used.

Tried using `.lastIndexOf()` but didn't find a way to define a non-zero digit.

**Input**

```
1.23400
1.00050
1.03456
```

**Output**

```
['1.234', '00']
['1.0005', '0']
['1.03456']
```

Comment: Cast your float to a string and use a regex.

Comment: I agree with btoueg, I'll write a little piece of code showing this.

Comment: @btoueg: this is useless. The input is already a string. Because if it is a float there are not zero to the end of number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex :

`/^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*?)(0*)$/`

```
/^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*?)(0*)$/.exec('1.23400'); // return ["1.23400", "1.234", "00"]
/^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*?)(0*)$/.exec('1.03456'); // return ["1.03456", "1.03456", ""]
```

You can use the parseFloat too if you juste interest by getting the significative part of the number.

```
parseFloat('1.23400') // return 1.234
```

Comment: When i put 1.03456 this return in alert :1.03456,1.03456,

Comment: Yes! This is the expected result.

Comment: Try to write `alert(["1.03456", "1.03456", ""])` in your JS console. And never ever use alert to debug JS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
'1.23400'.match(/^.*?(?=0*$)|0+$/g)
// ^.*?(?=0*$) : everything before zero or more trailing zeros
// 0+$         : one or more trailing zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lastIndexOfDigit(str) {
        var last_indices = [];
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(function (digit) {
            last_indices.push(str.lastIndexOf(digit));
        });
        var indices = last_indices.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
        return indices[indices.length - 1];
}
```